# SharePoint not always loading jquery in Word 365 "Online" add -in

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, office365api, office-js

I have created an Office add-in which side loads Documents in SharePoint into Word. 
To debug I use Word online, and open a more or less blank Word document in the same folder in SharePoint.
I then "Upload" my manifest file and initialise the add-in.
The add-in makes extensive use of jquery - and to avoid pitfalls I access a jquery file in the same folder set in SharePoint (hardcoded URL for now) rather than using the default SharePoint jquery.
So in SharePoint I have folders

Main Hosting folder

followed by

[image: SharePoint folders]

ContentDOCX has 1..n Word documents

Images all the images I use in the add-in (+ and - treeview for jquery)

Scripts Office js 1, jquery latest stable, and my add-in js

generated.aspx (the add-in html) with references to above scripts and images and sp.js from SharePoint /_layouts/15/ folder

and  a nearly empty testGen.docx - which I am using to debug the code - up to Word.run, at which point the browser naturally errors, but I can test the last in Word locally.

When I load using Word online, I can happily run, view debug, and Word locally all works fine.

But when I ask one of the team to test the add-in fails to load jquery treeview, so they get an ugly badly designed bullet list, and a broken up web page in their add-in. Both online Word, via a browser and local Word.

Comparing browser settings in IE 11, they look identical.
We all have the same level of access to the SharePoint folders

Any suggestions regarding what might be preventing the scripts from running on the team machines? (Antivirus and firewall have both been checked)

One of the team can load a locally based copy I built, and jquery treeview works, but SharePoint fails - so it seems to point at remote web or SharePoint access.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a stupid error on my part!
When you copy sets of files to SharePoint using OneDrive for business they load as "checked in" - so all the html, JavaScript files etc. were safely checked in.

What I didn't know is that css files dragged into "Custom" folder in the sites Style library are not checked in.

Here's the odd part, not checked in files will work for the creator, but not for anyone else.

Once I was able to get to another users machine with debugging, I could see the CSS files were not being found (this was the misleading part, as jQuery was available, but tree-view is reliant on the CSS!) A quick browse on the same users machine to the Style Library and I noticed the CSS files were not visible! A quick check-in and all immediately worked fine!

Oh well you live and you learn!

Thanks to all who took time to look at this.